# Rally burndown chart pulled programmatically

Tags: rally, burndowncharts

How to pull rally burndown charts using rally based API's programmatically using C#? Could a working example be shared?

Comment: Thanks for your reply...Could could you share me a example of the JavascriptAppSDK

Answer (score 0):

The only toolkit that loads charts programmatically(those are the same charts available on Reports>Reports page) is javascript AppSDK, which is using [StandardReport](https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0/doc/#!/api/Rally.ui.report.StandardReport-cfg-reportConfig) component. There is no [WS API](https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/doc/webservice/) endpoint that gets charts, and [.NET toolkit](https://github.com/RallyTools/RallyRestToolkitFor.NET) does not have support for it.

Comment: hanks for your reply...Could could you share me a working example this?